# Get type specification char from MySQLi field

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

In MySQLi's prepared statement API, [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) takes a type specification char.

[image: Type specification chars]

MySQLi's [`fetch_field`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) returns an object with several properties related to the field.  However, the type specification char is not one of the available properties (`$field->type` returns an integer corresponding to a constant, not a type specification char).

What is the best way to get the type specification char from a MySQLi field?

Comment: `mysqli_result::fetch_field()` should return the field's data-type. Is that good enough or do you specifically need one of those letters? I'm not sure how a bind_param argument would tie into fetch_field...

Comment: @MikeB My goal is to get specifically the type specification char; I could create my own method, but I feel like this would be something that can be done via the core API.

Comment: Does it matter? Type does not map 1:1 with the types that bind_param uses. You will have to create your own conversion array.

Comment: @MikeB Thanks, but I'll likely use the [MySQLi constants](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php) to avoid any issues should the values change in the future. datasage, thanks, that answers my question of whether I would need to write my own method or whether one existed already.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what reason do you need to have the specific types? PHP is a dynamically typed language, so it really shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Supericy I have several tables that have user-defined columns, and I am writing a script to handle input to update these columns with. I could neglect from using prepared statements to simplify the process, but I prefer trying to use them whenever possible. And from my understanding of MySQLi's prepared statements, the type specification char must be relevant to the param being bound.

Comment: You could do everything as type `s`. Mysql will automatically convert strings to the column's declared datatype.

Comment: @Barmar That's perfect, thanks. If you write it up in an answer (with something brief to more directly address the question too), I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just treat everything as a string, and use type `s`. The mysql server automatically converts strings to the column's actual datatype when processing queries, e.g. you can write things like `set int_col = '32'` and it will treat it as `set int_col = 32`.

There's a little extra overhead, since numeric data won't be transmitted in binary; the server will have to parse them. But unless you're doing a huge number of INSERT or UPDATE statements this will probably be negligible.